# Typescript switch map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I have the following TS code with multiple interfaces, components and a key/interface map.

```js
interface FooProps {
    'keyInFoo': string
}
const Foo = (props: FooProps) => {}

interface BarProps {
    'keyInBar': string
}
const Bar = (props: BarProps) => {}

interface PropsMap {
    'foo': FooProps,
    'bar': BarProps,
    //.. baz, etc...
}
type keyName = keyof PropsMap

const MyFunc = <T extends keyName>(key: T)  => {
    const props: PropsMap[T] = getProps(key)

    switch(key) {
        // We should know since T == typeof key === 'foo'
        // that typeof props === FooProps
        case 'foo': return Foo(props) // <- ERROR: Property ''keyInFoo'' is missing in type 'BarProps'
        case 'bar': return Bar(props) // <- ERROR Property ''keyInBar'' is missing in type 'FooProps'
    }
}

const getProps = <T extends keyName>(key: T): PropsMap[T] => {
    // ... some logic to get the props
    return {} as PropsMap[T]
}
```

I want to run a switch/if-else statement against the key of the map, and have TypeScript know the value of `props` in each case.

Of course, I could just assert `props as FooProps` etc. in each case, but I feel like there should be a way to have TS infer the type.

I've also tried using a generic type as a map with no additional success:

```js
type PropsGeneric<T extends keyName> = 
    T extends 'foo' ? FooProps :
    T extends 'bar' ? BarProps : never;
```

See [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0AUroA4DOyA3gFDIXIDkA1hAJ4CSIG6VAXMgWFKAOakAvqQToQ3NJmQBeZAAo8uQp1Y58BAJQyAfCWGlQkWIhQAhOFDWES5SrQbNzUDlx78hIsRKcz5i9ZxOVpo6eqQG4NDwSMjBALJweDaU1DCYLqpKBAA0thRUAEYWLkFZuSkA9BUAdNXIRQBe2cgQYAi11R5g9HgodPQAcnAAtiiy-egwsVkJeOGi4mDIcfSoAK4gCL4APAAqLQAekCAAJkT9Q6Pacv2cu1qhZCkLEv7K0+qzANq7ALq+fFawRuDA04RSBAA7sA2gALEH0LRPFKUKrIADqKAIsPQawANidkDQQOhIVxQDF9tJZN1epMiQwZNTUuk8ii0WBYXAlrSIPS3kRqbJMuo2c84AQUFQ0mxOFBWmsoCBJOgFFkwSjKAgJVKis45QqlcgnGr1BrKMJ9C8loCwMEdvsIEcIKdzgxLhBrrdkPdOPFEj9-tJdMiKGiOlx0KNkHj0HxgFswOhkLbkJyUAK2fKwIrlcRBMgJR9CN8-kIgA)

---

A working, but verbose solution I've come up with is to create a type guard for each key, and use this in a series of if-else if statements within `MyFunc`

```
const isFoo = <T extends keyName>(key: T, props: PropsMap[T]): props is FooProps => key === 'foo'
const isBar = <T extends keyName>(key: T, props: PropsMap[T]): props is BarProps => key === 'bar'

// ... etc
```

Comment: You probably need something like this: https://tsplay.dev/wRz2Qw. Its pretty verbose, but you get the full type-safety. Would this fit your needs?

Comment: That looks like it should work! Definitely pretty verbose, but still better than N type guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already noticed, it is tricky to make TypeScript understand the typings of functions implementations when generics are involved. Narrowing the type of `props` by checking the value of `key` when both are generic types does not work. Both types stay untouched by the compiler.

The first thing I would change is the `PropsMap`. Let's use the types of the functions as the value types so we can use the `ReturnType` and `Parameters` utility types later.

```
interface PropsMap {
    'foo': typeof Foo,
    'bar': typeof Bar
}
type keyName = keyof PropsMap

const getProps = <T extends keyName>(key: T): Parameters<PropsMap[T]>[0] => {
    // ... some logic to get the props
    return {} as Parameters<PropsMap[T]>[0]
}
```

There are a few ways to write conditionals, so that TypeScript properly understands them. They mostly resemble some type of lookup object which can be strongly typed.

```
const MyFunc = <T extends keyName>(key: T)  => {
    const props = getProps(key)

    const ret: { 
      [K in keyName]: (arg: Parameters<PropsMap[K]>[0]) => ReturnType<PropsMap[K]> 
    }[T] = {
        foo(props: FooProps) {
            return Foo(props)
        },
        bar(props: BarProps) {
            return Bar(props)
        }
    }[key]

    return ret(props)
}
```

Our lookup-object called `ret` is typed with a mapped type. For each key in `PropsMap`, `ret` also has a corresponding key which holds a method. Each method takes `props` as its parameter. The `props` parameter and the return type of the methods are strictly typed by the mapped type.

All that's  left to do is to call `ret` with the `props`.

This leaves us with an implementation that frankly is quite verbose and also has some runtime overhead due to the added function call. But it is a way to strongly type the implementation without type assertions.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0AUroA4DOyA3gFDIXIDkA1hAJ4CSIG6VAXMgWFKAOakAvqQToQ3NJmQBeZAAo8uQp1Y58BAJQyAfMgBEARgBMAZj2lSoSLEQoAQnChrCJcpVoNmDqBy49+QiJiEt4y8orqnN7OmjrIxiYWVtDwSMgxALJweK6U1DCYvmD0eBDoMJLoADRuFFQARo5FJWUV3oHFpch09ABycAC2KLI95elKBFl4FqLiYMgZ9KgAriAIYQA8ACrIEAAekCAAJkQ9-UPacj2cW1pxZHmzEhEusnwQYDFXDBoWj8HzKAfTjEZAAbQA0shQN0GOcIABdThyRx8ThYRyDD7QAgbTLZSEI7RggAMCK00l0ACUPssoCAti08RMpoTdIIwVsEWEHnlKAV0AoJipMDEtLy+XygWA6SBKkL1L9JRRBDVlchGlAFcpkNEJuLaurkNLZbrHNrNIa8sJrWCegi-pQTfTjR8Lb9hEE5sh3p8JpsdvtDidYX0sZdrshbujMUNrLj8XhOUTSdzKblKAB6TPIAB0+a46CGyAANug+MB1mB0D6PsgwAALFAvAiG51y4iCZBwIgYqBY+PM9SsrnEslCIA)